# How to add class on Foundation 6 range-slider when the slider-handle moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me. I can't addClass() or make anything happen when the slider changes, with Foundation 6 and jQuery. Help me. I want to addClass() when the value of the slider changes, so I can change the content of a span element. This is what my code looks like:

```
<div class="slider" data-slider  data-initial-start="20" data-end="100" data-binding="true">
<span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderOutput2" data-start="0" data-end="10"></span>
<span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
<input data-binding="true" type="hidden">
</div>

    <span class="damn" data-n="1">Hey</span>
    <span class="damn" data-n="2">Boo</span>
    <span class="damn" data-n="3">You OK?</span>
```

And the jQuery:

```
 var stepsof = [1, 2, 3];
        $('input[type="hidden"]').on('change', function(){
            $(".slider").val(valMap[ui.values[0]]);
       $('span[data-n="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
           $('.damn').addClass('goat');


        });
```

Comment: could it be you have another hidden input - can you not make the event more specific? In this case, `$('.slider input[type="hidden"]')` or give the input an id ?

Comment: No... it's something else... please help me... still trying anything I can find and think of, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

since many people may happen to get stuck on this, I would like to share how this is done since I got the help I needed : ) .

```
 <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="1" data-end="3">
 <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="slider_value"></span>
<span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>


<input id="slider_value" type="hidden">
</div>
```

And the span elements

```
<span class="selector-span great" data-n="1">First</span>
<span class="selector-span" data-n="2">Second</span>
<span class="selector-span" data-n="3">Third</span>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('.slider').on('moved.zf.slider', function() {

    console.log($('#slider_value').val());
    $('.selector-span').removeClass('logoopen');
    $('.selector-span').removeClass('open');
    $('.selector-span[data-n="' + $('#slider_value').val() +'"]').addClass('open');
    });
```